# Include/exclude exceptions in camel resilience4J

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

How to include/exclude exceptions from profiling while implementing circuit breaker pattern using resilience4J library in camel route(spring-boot application).

we are using the following official library but it doesn't expose any API to include exclude the exceptions like the plain java library.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-resilience4j-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

but the official documentation says there are API's to handle these conditions :
https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker

```
// Create a custom configuration for a CircuitBreaker
CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
  .failureRateThreshold(50)
  .slowCallRateThreshold(50)
  .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
  .slowCallDurationThreshold(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
  .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(3)
  .minimumNumberOfCalls(10)
  .slidingWindowType(SlidingWindowType.TIME_BASED)
  .slidingWindowSize(5)
  .recordException(e -> INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
                 .equals(getResponse().getStatus()))
  .recordExceptions(IOException.class, TimeoutException.class)
  .ignoreExceptions(BusinessException.class, OtherBusinessException.class)
  .build();
```

Comment: have you found an answer to this? or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to set `camel.resilience4j.circuit-breaker` in your config file `application.properties` something like `camel.resilience4j.circuit-breaker=circuitBreaker`
2. You need to create a bean with the name you have in the config like

```
@Bean
public CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker() {
    CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
      .failureRateThreshold(50)
      .slowCallRateThreshold(50)
      .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
      .slowCallDurationThreshold(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
      .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(3)
      .minimumNumberOfCalls(10)
      .slidingWindowType(SlidingWindowType.TIME_BASED)
      .slidingWindowSize(5)
      .recordException(e -> INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
                     .equals(getResponse().getStatus()))
      .recordExceptions(IOException.class, TimeoutException.class)
      .ignoreExceptions(BusinessException.class, OtherBusinessException.class)
      .build();
      CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry =
            CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(circuitBreakerConfig);

      return circuitBreakerRegistry.circuitBreaker("circuitBreaker");
}
```

instead of using config you can use the name on the route itself like `circuitBreaker().resilience4jConfiguration().circuitBreaker("circuitBreaker").end()`

This works in camel 3.17.x